# Which kernel version fixes the issue of dell touchpads being recognized as a mouse?

Tags: kernel, dell, touchpad

On Ubuntu 14.04 a kernel update seems to fix the problem that the touchpad is just recognized as a mouse.

Which kernel version fixes this issue?

Related thread is here.

[Dell Trackpad not recognized in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/496314/313088)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and to the following:

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Choose the one that you want and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-your_version_choice
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to perfrom a system update.

Answer (score 0):

3.13.0-24-generic kernel

Source:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1265885